# Error "make all" /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf when installing caffe

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe, ubuntu-18.04, protoc

I want to install caffe with conda. In the tutorial I followed it was told to install these stuff

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
```

Soon I found out that is was out-of-date and removed both of them and got latest protoc 3.9.1 . But I'm facing an error that said there is no protobuff in the folder.
I got confused about protobuf lib and protoc.
I have only one protoc in this folder

```
protoc: /usr/bin/protoc
```

And here's what I have after performing

```
sudo make all -j4

CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools
/convert_imageset.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin] Error 1
make: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools
/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin]
Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
```

Can you help me solving this issue? And also it would be great if you explain me the matter with protoc and protobuff

Comment: Hi Michael! Could you solve the problem? And were you able to shed some light on protoc and protobuff?

Comment: Oi, that was long time ago. I had a lot of stuff installed already on my machine and my python path was mixed with conda one so I made a virtual environment and installed all the dependencies with required versions. Somehow it worked

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that (fingers crossed)